# documentation for "<<<" in bash shell

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, variables

The following works in bsd unix, bash shell:

```
stuff=$(echo "dog cat rat")

read -r -a astuff <<< "$stuff"

for file in "${astuff[@]}"; do echo "file=$file"; done
```

Clearly the line containing `<<<` breaks `$stuff` into an array and puts the array into astuff. But I do not understand the syntax. Is there a man page or other documentation for `<<<`? And how does this break the string at spaces?

Comment: It's `read` that splits the string around spaces (more precisely, around characters of $IFS).

Comment: `<<<` introduces a "here string" - search for that on [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Comment: [This](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) is another good ressource on here strings.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80362/what-does-mean might also help

Comment: And the assignment is a classic [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Comment: (Aside: The reason I didn't mark-as-dupe myself is that this also was asking about the array-splitting, not found in the other question; the top-voted answer's failure to address that aspect is also why I added my own. But it was a decision that could have gone either way, and I don't feel compelled to reopen).

Answer (score 4):

It's called *here strings*. You can read [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html).

> Here Strings
>          A variant of here documents, the format is:
>
> ```
>           [n]<<<word
>
>    The word undergoes brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and
>    variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and
>    quote removal.  Pathname expansion and word splitting are not
>    performed.  The result is supplied as a single string, with a newline
>    appended, to the command on its standard input (or file descriptor n
>    if n is specified).
> ```

Comment: Nice. A more direct link to an explanation: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html.

Comment: Please don't link to the ABS. It's full of errors and bad practices. Here's a link to the [official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings)

Comment: @MarkA.Fitzgerald, ...if you want some better-regarded links than the ABS that are less formal than the official documentation, you might also consider [the bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection#here_strings), or [the Wooledge wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument) (here-strings covered near the bottom of the page). The ABS is the w3schools of shell scripting -- infamous for spreading bad practices and outdated information.

Comment: Nice direct link, @chepner, and thanks for the heads-up regarding the quality of the ABS.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: nice analogy to w3schools re: the ABS - good to know.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
read -r -a astuff <<< "$stuff"
```

...`<<<` is "here-string" syntax, syntactic sugar providing a shorter way to write:

```
read -r -a astuff <<EOF
$stuff
EOF
```

`read` is thus the command responsible for assigning your content into `astuff`; the `-a` argument tells it to split on characters in `IFS` (by default, spaces, tabs and newlines) into an array.

---

References:

- [The bash-hackers wiki on herestrings](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection#here_strings)
- [The Wooledge wiki on heredocs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument)
- [The official bash manual on here-string syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings)

...and, on the `read` component:

- [The bash-hackers wiki on `read`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read)
- [The official bash manual on `read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read)

Answer (score 0):

You can search `man bash` for explanations. This is one possible way:

```
 $ man bash | grep -A10 -B4 "<<<"
```

It `grep`s for "<<<" in the output of `man bash`, displaying beside the line containing "<<<" also 4 lines before that line, and 10 lines after. On my Debian I get this result:

```
   Here Strings
       A variant of here documents, the format is:

              <<<word

       The  word  undergoes  brace  expansion,  tilde expansion, parameter and
       variable expansion, command  substitution,  arithmetic  expansion,  and
       quote  removal.   Pathname  expansion  and  word splitting are not per‐
       formed.  The result is supplied as a single string to  the  command  on
       its standard input.
```

And 3 more lines, which are unrelated.

You can repeat this search for other words and "words" you don't understand.